# Which is the better way to get string from BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

I get `BufferedReader` from the following networking code.

```
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

1. I was wondering, which way give higher efficiency in term of execution speed?
2. Is 1024 size a good choice for Android? Or, is there any system constant value I can use?

   ```
       int charRead = 0;
       char[] buffer = new char[1024];
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       while ((charRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           stringBuffer.append(buffer, 0, charRead);
       }
   ```

---

```
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first approach is more efficient, but I'd rather set higher buffer size ex. 8*1024. This is default CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE in HttpClient.
I'd rather say that something below 8*1024 is unreasonable because most of HTTP buffers are set to 8*1024.

In the second approach you're assuming new line characters in the stream. What in case of 20MB json optimized in such way that there is no new line characters? This will blow your app.

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

In my opinion the best choice is to use multiplication of 8*1024. The upper constraint is bound to size of memory and connection speed with respect to stream's buffer processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringBuilder` is considered a better alternative to `StringBuffer` unless you need the overhead of using the synchronized `StringBuffer`.  (`StringBuilder` is a drop in replacement)

As for performance, I'd go with the first approach and avoid using `readLine()` unless you need to process the line as a line of text.  Also, `readLine()` doesn't return the actual linefeeds, so the data you a creating int your second example will be missing linefeeds, and therefore may not be exactly as it was transmitted from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the StringBuilder tip. I almost forget that.

Answer (score 0):

May be set higher buffer limit would be best option.

As per java doc

> The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large enough for most purposes.

Buffering is better approach. Again as per doc

> Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

Comment: But the problem is, if I do not specific size, how am I going to construct a char array?